# How to get board, list, and card last updated timestamp using the Trello API?

Tags: trello

I am working on syncing Trello with my own tool in Unity.

When synchronizing I want to check who made the last edit so I can decide to download to Unity or upload to Trello. I have tried but can't find a way to see when a board, list, or card has been updated last.

Is it possible to get this information using the Trello API?